# Can I detect the width of a dynamicaly filled div box without rendering it on the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I detect the width of a dynamicaly filled div box without rendering it on the web page?

```
<div>{{some.data.from.some.model}}</div>
```

If I render it, I know it's width is 260px (in every modern browser).

**Can I detect it, before it is rendered on the web page? Are there tools, mechanisms, libraries to do that?**

**My Imagination is:**

1. That is the div box width this class (margin, padding, whatever)
2. This is the content (text, font, fontsize, whatever..)
3. Tell me it's width
4. Don't show it on the homepage yet, I'll decide afterwards

Comment: there are several elements with unknown width-values and I want to know which of them can I put into a certain group. But the approach is not the question, please don't clamp on it, thank you!

Comment: can you not like hide it using visibility: hidden at some remote offset after positioning it using position: absolute; remote offset meaning off the viewport. You might still get what you want in case you don't want to show this on the page.

Comment: dear deceze, that is not a XY problem.

Comment: @82Tuskers: do I have to render it? Are there no tools such of pre-renderers or something like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the size of an element that doesn't exist (hasn't been rendered). Any solution you find to calculating an element's size without it being rendered is probably not going to be cross-browser.

So, the best you can do is render said element out of view, be it via "visibility: hidden", or pushing it out of view with "display: fixed". Once you have an actual element, you can check it's size for the current browser via JS and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Instead of pushing it out of view (which may cause scrolling issues until it is removed), how about just rendering it with a low z-index?

Comment: @sideroxylon A fixed element isn't taken into account when laying out it's parent, nor will it trigger any scrolls. Using z-index by itself won't help, as it will just be another relativ positioned element at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5wq8o02q/.

HTML

```
<div id="playground" class="block"> 
    some content 
</div>

<span id="width"> </span>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    /* width: 100px; */
    height: 100px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    //$('#playground').css('visibility','hidden');
    $('#playground').css('display','none');
    $('#width').html($('#playground').css('width'));
});
```

It helps to use display: none and it won't use screen real estate as visibility: hidden. It still gives the width you are looking for (I think). Let me know me it helps ...

Comment: the current problem is  a little bit complicated: it is within angular, data comes from REST asyncron and the timing can differ (I don't know, when it comes), therefore I would like to calculate the space, before it is here, so that no design jumps can occur regarding coming elements-width .

Comment: display none will not allow any design jumps at all. In fact visibility: hidden will in the marked answer. Btw, how do you propose to know the size of the content that is about to come without receiving it. I suggest you let the content come in and show it in case it satisfies your constraints using display: none.

Comment: I see, that's the way only.. A kind of pre-rendering mechanism would be great (maybe in the future..)